# How to find an object containing a value in the list of its field on Stream. How to change the code to Stream?

Tags: java, stream

```
public class User {

   private int id;

   Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<>();

   public Set<Phone> setPhones(Set<Phone> phones) {
       return this.phones = phones;
   }

   public Collection<Phone> getPhones() {
       return this.phones;
   }
```

```
public class Phone {

   private int id;

   private String value;

   public String getValue() {
       return value;
   }
```

there are two classes. You need to find User that contains a specific phone number. I tried to redo it on the stream, but it doesn't work.
The usual code:

```
public User findByPhone1(String number) {
       var users = findAll();
       User user = null;
       if (users != null) {
           for (User u : users) {
               var phones = u.getPhones();
               if (phones != null) {
                   for (Phone p : phones) {
                       if (p.getValue().equals(number)) {
                           user = u;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return user;
   }
```

I wanted to do something like this, but it's impossible:

```
public User findByPhone(String number) {
        var list = findAll();
       return var user = list.stream()
                .filter(u -> u.getPhones().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue().equals(number)))
                .findFirst();
}
```

Are there any other options?

Comment: Instead of the inner `filter(...)` which checks the number, try `anyMatch(...)`. `filter()` returns the stream and this won't be a valid return value for the predicate of the outer `filter()`. Also note that your loop contains some null checks that you need to add to your stream, again using `filter()`, e.g. `filter(u -> u.getPhones() != null )`.

Comment: You used `allMatch()` instead of `anyMatch()` like I suggested. `allMatch()` means _all_ phone numbers must match which is unlikely if a user has more than one ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's how it works! It happens that sometimes i don't notice